# How to install a pre-installed device specific app on another device?

Tags: applications

I don't know how to explain, so let me give an example,

Suppose I have a samsung device and a HTC device,
And I extract the apk file of music application from my HTC device, and install it on my samsung device it does not work.

So is there any way to make application from another manufacturer to work on some other device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant just normally install device specific APKs to some other device (especially from different vendor).

This is because it needs to be **ported**. Device specific apps use styles and layout and classes which are defined in that particular device's framework (in your case HTC). So to use that app in Samsung you will have to pull out all those classes and layouts from HTC into Samsung and merge with code. And this is a very difficult task.

However, if you still want to try your luck, system default APKs dont install like normal APKs. We just push them to `/system/app` and st permissions to `755` or `rw-r-r` and restart phone. This method works regardless of device (but again, I really dont think music app will work even this way. It needs to be ported as told in above paragraph).